# MySQL | Can I store table name within a different table?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to store a table (or a table reference) within another table, perhaps as a BLOB type?

I have four tables: subject, pupil, pupil_age & staff. I want to create a master table that lists the tables, and some other details such as table name (table_desc) for the user to see.

For example:

```
table_id--|--table_name--|--table_desc
----------|--------------|------------
-------0--|--subject-----|--Subjects--
-------1--|--pupil-------|--Pupils----
-------2--|--pupil_age---|--Pupil age-
-------3--|--staff-------|--Staff-----
```

I don't want to store table_name as text, but rather as a data type that allows me to perform actions on it.

I have a javascipt menu that allows the user to filter, e.g. for pupil_age = 11 or staff_id=10078.

Currently the menu shows like this when you hover on 'Add filter':

```
Add filter > Pupils
-----------> Staff
-----------> Subject
```

Hovering on Pupils reveals two further options, and then the values show when you hover on Pupil age:

```
Add filter > Pupils > Pupil name 
--------------------> Pupil age > 11
--------------------------------> 12
--------------------------------> 13
-----------> Staff
-----------> Subject
```

In this example, pupil is a table containing name, while pupil_age is a table containing the values 11, 12, 13.

I would like to drive this menu, server-side, from the tables themselves. I'm using MySQL but my question is whether this is possible in any DB.

My latest thinking was whether a table can contain objects such as table names that are recognised as tables, rather than storing as text.

Any help appreciated greatly

Emma

Comment: You need dynamic mysql,esentially CONCATing a string together and then executing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no special datatype in MySQL for storing "table_name", "column_name", et al.

To answer the question you seem to be asking, whether it's possible, within a single query, to return values from a column, and then use those values as identifier (table_name, column_name) within a SQL query... the answer to that is no. Not within a single statement.

To answer the question in the title, yes, it's possible to store a table_name in a column. (Note that 
MySQL provides schema information in a database named **`information_schema`**. The datatypes of the columns in the **`information_schema.tables`** and **`information_schema.columns`** tables would be an appropriate choice for datatypes if you need to store schema information in your own tables.

---

If you gain an understanding of how DBMS executes a SQL statement, that is, the actual sequence of steps in processing SQL text... i.e. the syntax check (recognizing keywords, recognizing identifiers, in appropriate sequence, etc.), the semantic check (identifiers refer to valid database objects, user executing the statement has appropriate privileges), preparing the execution plan (available indexes, possible join permutations), and then executing the prepared plan...

Then it will become apparent why a column value, returned from the execution of the statement (or a value supplied as a bind parameter) cannot be referred to as identifier in the statement.

Comment: Thank you for your swift - and, I suspect, correct - reply. You are perfectly right that I am trying to store values in a table and then use them as identifiers in a subsequent query. Do you think PL/SQL or a non-MySQL DB could handle it?

Comment: @emma: No database will handle that within a single SQL statement. Every relational database I'm aware of has some mechanism for retrieving schema information. And any database will allow you to submit subsequent statements that make use of the retrieved schema information. But I don't know of any database that will allow you to achieve this in a single statement, aside from a call to a stored program. (It's possible in MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, et al. to write a PROCEDURE that can run multiple statements, to achieve a particular result but we're more apt to do this in application not the db.

Comment: @Emma: within a stored program, creating a string and then submitting that to the database as a SQL statement is called "dynamic SQL".  And  MySQL stored programs have a mechanism that supports that, refer to the documentation on the `PREPARE` statement.) Oracle PL/SQL and SQL Server Transact-SQL provide equivalent functionality.